# shape builder is not intersecting

Tags: adobe-illustrator

[image]I want to keep the overlapping portion of the caterpillar and the half circles.
Shape builder is not letting me do that.
I have arranged, rearranged their position (bring front, etc). But they are not intersecting at all.
I have checked all of them in outline mode, they all are drawn in usual shape.
I do not understand.
Please help.
[image]

Comment: Are you trying to keep the caterpillar as a solid shape, but break the half circles?

Comment: Indeed my caterpillar is a solid shape. I want to draw a stripe-like tiger...

Comment: **How** are you using Shape Builder?? There's no information on *anything* regarding your procedure. Are you dragging with Shape Builder? Clicking? On what? Merely choosing the Shape Builder Tool does *nothing* until you tell it to.

Comment: I drew the caterpillar with stroke, then cut a portion from that using the eraser tool. converted from stroke to fill, got the shape. added spike selected all applied pathfinder to make it a solid shape. took two circles, applied minus front, got the half-circle. set anchor point and rotated that 3/5 times. Select entire thing (caterpillar and circles) and then,  only then I clicked shape builder holding alt tried to delete the unwanted part.

Comment: I know how to use a shape builder. but never face anything like this.the body of caterpillar and all those half circles are acting like individual shape, no intersecting parts were there.

Comment: **all of that** should be part of the question. I wasn't suggesting you don't know how to use Shape builder.. but the question amounts to "My car won't run! Why?"  -- How is anyone supposed to know based on that information?? Half circles are most likely a group or compound shape that needs releasing. Most pathfinder operations result in a  group or compound shape.

Comment: I am sorry. I didn't know what to include and what not to. :( :'(

Comment: What's that rectangle around the caterpillar shape? Is there some sort of odd raster image fill there? Is it a symbol by chance?

Comment: that rectangle- I didn't get that either. no raster image in this file. I drew every single element from scratch.

Comment: What I do not understand is- why none of these figures are intersecting, usually overlapping part highlights whenever you hover shape builder on them. in this case that is not happening.

Comment: Hard to say.. My *guess* would be that rectangle, whatever it is, is the issue. The rectangle generally means a mask, a raster image, a mesh object... Shape Builder won't work on any of those. My suggestion.... use the **Direct Selection Tool** to select the shapes individually in Outline Mode.. copy, paste to a new document and try again with Shape Builder.

Comment: Thank you for the instructions. yes, I started to redraw the whole thing.  :( :'(

Comment: I hope you didn't get too far into redrawing, the solution you need should be below.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

if you just want to divide all the pieces so that you can change them separately, I would use the Divide Tool, instead of the shape builder tool.  See attached photo.

[image: Illustrator Divide Tool]

If you use the shape tool and just single click in the middle of the overlapping area that you want to separate, it essentially cuts it.

Here I have some overlapping shapes which are currently solid rectangles:

[image: Solid Shapes]

Here I highlighted the overlapping part that I want to cut, with the shape building tool:

[image: click with shape builder tool]

After single clicking with the Shape Builder tool, you can see how the shapes are now separated:

[image: after the shape builder separates]

Comment: I should add, I would do a copy and paste in front and move your original caterpillar shape to a different layer in case you want to go back to it.  It's always better to work with a solid underlying shape, and place the different blocks on top of that.

Comment: Thank you so much.  wish I got this earlier. had to redraw everything. :'(

Comment: I'm sorry, with the time difference, I commented right as I was leaving work and didn't see your answers until the next morning.  but hopefully it will help you for future, and maybe someone else someday.